# Java TimeoutException on Ubuntu on SoftLayer

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, java, http, socket

I have java application, that works fine on my local machine.

But when I'm trying to start it on SoftLayer, ALL connection is toooo long.

For example, simple http connection via HttpAsync or others (socket, etc.) lasts 1-2 min. But after connection completed, data sends/receives fast. I can't figure what the problem.

I thought that mb problem with apf-firewall. But even on server with no firewall I have this problem.

So...something blocks my connections in **Java**. Simple curl to the same url is fast.

How can I find the problem?

**UPD:** it happens even if I trying to connect to local service on 127.0.0.1

**UPD2:** but when I start project in IDE, there is no such problem. Problem occurs only with manual start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's magic but...

As you know, you can export project 3 dif ways:

1. Extract required libraries into JAR.
2. Package required libraries into JAR.
3. Copy required libraries into sub folder next to JAR.

I always used 2. But tried 3, and problem solved now. It works, but I really don't understand why.

If someone can explain this behavior I will accept his answer.